# "System.threading.threadStart' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context'? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, delegates, lambda

I got the error on `var ts = System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate()` (Red line has drown under `System.Threading.ThreadStart`). What is the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public Program()
        {
            int[] iArray = new int[3];
            iArray[0] = 2;
            iArray[1] = 1;
            iArray[2] = 5;
            var ts = System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate()
            {
                foreach (int i in iArray)
                    Foo(i);
            });
        }

        public void Foo(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + ",");
        }

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `new`:

```
var ts = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate()
         {
             foreach (int i in iArray)
                 Foo(i);
         });
```

BTW:

You don't have to prefix `ThreadStart` with its namespace `System.Threading`, because you already have a `using` declaration for it at the top of your *.cs file.

Comment: Well, .. I don't know if to thank you for solving it, or just get angry with you, because you showed me out how much stupid I was. 

But I'm just kidding. I should pay a bit more attention. thank you!  :)